# txpostgres stored procedure returns cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, twisted

I'm trying to get a cursor from stored procedure in txpostgres. 
Psycopg2 has a named cursors which are working fine for it. But there is no `curs = conn.cursor('name')` statement in txpostgres.

Is there another way to get it ?

Answer (score 1):

txpostgres doesn't have a named cursor feature.  However, psycopg2's named cursors are just a convenience wrapper for [PostgreSQL's cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).  I don't have much experience with stored procedures, but here's an example with a simple query:

```
@inlineCallbacks
def transaction(cursor):
    yield cursor.execute('mycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT bigtable')
    yield cursor.execute('FETCH ALL FROM mycursor')
    data = yield cursor.fetchall()

conn.runInteraction(transaction)
```